# What are the pros and cons of using webworks versus J2ME and vice versa in blackberry development?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, blackberry-webworks

I have written some basic applications using J2Me and felt that getting things done in terms of UI/UX were a night mare especially with blackberry OS 5. I then started playing around with Webworks and found it to be better and faster however i keep getting told that it is better to stick with J2ME. Which one is a better choice? Is one limited in features than the other? What will RIM support for the long term future?

Answer (score 1):

This is a decision to be made for each application.

How well do you know HTML, Javascript, and CSS? How much device integration do you need? How graphics intensive will the application be?

HTML et al have a much lower learning curve than J2ME and the RIM APIs. You are missing some of the more functionality that integrates deep into the phones abilities. But you have a distinct advantage in that anything that you find missing in the Webworks libraries, you can write as Javascript extension in Java.

Webworks itself is limited to the blackberry platform, but **HTML, Javascript, and CSS are practically universal**. It's simple to turn the application into something that will work in a web browser. Just take out Javascript calls to any blackberry.* apis (or wrap their use in blocks like `if (blackberry) {`), and redirect anything in an XMLHTTPRequest to be proxied through something on the local server. I'm doing it this way for a Playbook app I'm working on. It's nice that I can show others that don't use a BB the functionality of my app.

It's probably pretty easy to take your Webworks app and alter it for another framework like Adobe AIR or PhoneGap (I haven't tried, but intend to at some point).

Answer (score 1):

From experience, Webworks seems to be easier to develop in terms of UI. But in terms in functionality, there isn't much. I don't know if they've changed this, but before, if there wasn't specific functionality in Webworks, you could create your own by porting the Java code over and creating your own extension.

I would say that using J2ME, would be the better choice if you need more integration with device functionality, rather than UI.